# What should I do when the anime I want to tag doesn't have on the tag list?

Tags: support

Currently I want to ask some question about an anime call "Dororo" but it didn't show on at the Tags list.

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally the solution is to create the required tag yourself. However, this is not possible without first having accumulated 300 reputation points.

To get around this, simply tag your question with *some* relevant tag, or an even an irrelevant one, and leave a comment asking for the creation of a new tag, or ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-). Someone will come along and help you.

As another option, though I'm not sure if this is a good solution, the [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) tag exists for this purpose, to serve as a placeholder until the proper tag is added, per its usage guidance:

> If you don't have permission to create a tag for an anime/manga that isn't already in the system, please use this tag and someone will create it for you. Be sure to state the name of the series in your question!

Comment: Alright, I follow your instructions.